# Recurring Azure functions using Python 3.8

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-automation

I am currently using Task Scheduler to run a python file once per day that webscrapes data from a number of webpages using Selenium, then stores the results in a CSV. This CSV is then transformed into matplotlib graphs and stored in a PDF weekly.

I decided to move this work out to Azure as my computer is not always on, however am having many difficulties finding which resources to use on the Azure portal.

- I have tried using WebApps but Azure does not support Linux webjobs which is the only thing python runs on.
- I have tried Azure Automation accounts using Runbooks but am having many problems uploading my packages, recieving this error for the pandas package
  "Orchestrator.Activities.PythonPackageExtractException: Error while extractinig Python package: Unexpected file structure in .whl file for python package pandas. It is likely that the package is for an unsupported platform. at Orchestrator.Activities.SetModuleActivity.ExecuteInternal(CodeActivityContext context, Byte[] moduleContent, String moduleName, ModuleLanguage moduleLanguage, Guid moduleVersionId, String modulePath) at Orchestrator.Activities.SetModuleActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)". While I know this error is a result of not being able to resolve dependencies I followed the instructions listed here and switched my python to run on python2, [Error installing Python 2 packages in Azure Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219327/error-installing-python-2-packages-in-azure-automation) to no avail.
- I have also tried Azure Function apps with functions and was given yet another message "Editing functions in the Azure portal is not supported for Linux Consumption Function Apps."

My code is written in Python 3.8 and am completely lost on the right tool for this job, everywhere I seem to look comes with some issues I cant resolve. Does anyone have any suggestions which of the three (or others) I should use for my needs, and point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use VS Code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-02

or Azure Functions CLI:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

then just use func init in a command line and select python as your programming language.